# How to customize Wizard control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am developing the first web application to me with this programming language. I am trying to use the Wizard Control for managing the user by developing the following scenario:
**Wizard Step1:** contains a TextBox where the admin can put the username of the user
and when he clicks on the next button the username will be checked a against the users table in the database; if he is existed in the database, his information will be shown in the Wizard Step2 and his information will be read-only. If he is not existed, the admin will be notified with a message.

**Wizard Step2:** contains a Repeater or Placeholder that shows the user information.

**Wizard Step3:** Also, if the user existed this step will show the current role of this user in the        system with showing a button for editing the role of him

My ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" DisplaySideBar="false" Width="80%" >
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" title="Employee Username/Network ID">
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="InputLabel">Username:</td>
                            <td class="InputControl">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:WizardStep>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" title="Manage User">
                    <div class="content">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>

                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                </asp:WizardStep>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep3" runat="server" Title="Edit User Role">
                    <label for="role">Current Role: </label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF99" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#000099" /> 
                    <asp:RadioButtonList id="radio1" runat="server" TextAlign="left">
                        <asp:ListItem id="option1" runat="server" value="Admin" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option2" runat="server" value="Contribute" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option3" runat="server" value="User" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Clicked" />
                </asp:WizardStep>
            </WizardSteps>

            <HeaderTemplate>
               <ul id="wizHeader">
                   <asp:Repeater ID="SideBarList" runat="server">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <li><a class="<%# GetClassForWizardStep(Container.DataItem) %>" title="<%#Eval("Name")%>">
                               <%# Eval("Name")%></a> </li>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:Repeater>
               </ul>
           </HeaderTemplate>

        </asp:Wizard>
```

And the Code-Behind is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class UserManagement : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string username = TextBox1.Text;

        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";
        string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Username = @Username";

        //For checking the user
        if (username != null)
        {
            if (CheckUsername(username) == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(myReader["Name"].ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine(myReader["JobTitle"].ToString());
                        Repeater1.DataSource = myReader;
                        Repeater1.DataBind();
                        myReader.Close();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        //For sending object to the Wizard1.PreRender
        Wizard1.PreRender += new EventHandler(Wizard1_PreRender);

    }


    //Method for checking the existence of the username in the database (retrun true or false)
    private bool CheckUsername(string username)
    {
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";
        string cmdText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM employee WHERE Username = '" + username + "'";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open(); // Open DB connection.

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
            {
                int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                // True (> 0) when the username exists, false (= 0) when the username does not exist.
                return (count > 0);
            }
        }

    }


    protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex == 1)
        {
            string username = TextBox1.Text;
        }
    }


    //Method for replacing the default sidebar of the Wizard Control with a custom sidebar (represented in a repeater)
    protected void Wizard1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater SideBarList = Wizard1.FindControl("HeaderContainer").FindControl("SideBarList") as Repeater;
        SideBarList.DataSource = Wizard1.WizardSteps;
        SideBarList.DataBind();
    }

    protected string GetClassForWizardStep(object wizardStep)
    {
        WizardStep step = wizardStep as WizardStep;

        if (step == null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        int stepIndex = Wizard1.WizardSteps.IndexOf(step);

        if (stepIndex < Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex)
        {
            return "prevStep";
        }
        else if (stepIndex > Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex)
        {
            return "nextStep";
        }
        else
        {
            return "currentStep";
        }
    }


    protected void Button1_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When the button is clicked,
        // show the new role of the user
        //Label1.Text = "...button clicked...";

    }



}



        //Session["Username"] = Username.Text;
        //String strUserName = Request.QueryString["Username"];

        //string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";
        //string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Username = @Username";

        ////For checking the user
        //if (Request.QueryString["Username"] != null)
        //{
        //    //String strUserName = Request.QueryString["Username"];

        //    ////Check userName Here
        //    //String strReturnStatus = "false";

        //    if (CheckUsername(Request.QueryString["Username"]) == true)
        //    {
        //        //strReturnStatus = "true";
        //        try
        //        {
        //            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        //            conn.Open();
        //            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        //            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
        //            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        //            while (myReader.Read())
        //            {
        //                Console.WriteLine(myReader["Name"].ToString());
        //                Console.WriteLine(myReader["JobTitle"].ToString());
        //                Repeater1.DataSource = myReader;
        //                Repeater1.DataBind();
        //                myReader.Close();
        //                conn.Close();
        //            }
        //        }
        //        catch (Exception ex)
        //        {
        //            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        //        }
        //    }
```

I am struggling with the code-behind a lot. It did not work even for checking the username and I don't know why. Also, I am not sure if I should put any piece of code inside  or not for showing the user information from the database.

---

**UPDATE:**

For the roles, I there are three tables for getting and setting the roles. The structure of them is as following:

**User table:** Name, Username, Department (Username is the primary key)

**Roles table:** RoleID, RoleName (RoleID is the primary key)

**UserRole table:** UserRoleID, Username, RoleID (UserRoleID is the primary key)

---

**ANOTHER UPDATE (LAST):**

**User table:** Name, Username, DepartmentCode (Username is the primary key)

**Department table table:** DepartmentCode, DepartmantName (DepartmentCode is the primary key)

**Roles table:** RoleID, RoleName (RoleID is the primary key)

**UserRole table:** UserRoleID, Username, RoleID (UserRoleID is the primary key)

I am using the following query in the Wizard1_NextButtonClick method:

```
protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Wizard1.WizardSteps[e.NextStepIndex].ID)
        {
            case "WizardStep2":
                string username = TextBox1.Text;
                string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";

                //For checking the user        
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && CheckUsername(username))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Session["Username"] = username;

                        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                        conn.Open();
                        //string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Username = @Username";
                        string cmdText = "SELECT dbo.employee.Username, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.employee.JobTitle, dbo.employee.BadgeNo," + 
                                                "ISNULL(dbo.Roles.RoleID, 3) AS RoleID, dbo.Divisions.DivisionName" +
                                         "FROM  dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode" + 
                                                "LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Roles RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.UserRole ON dbo.Roles.RoleID = dbo.UserRole.RoleID ON" + 
                                                "dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserRole.Username" +
                                         "WHERE     (dbo.employee.Username = @Username)";
                        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                        DataTable table = new DataTable();
                        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
                        adapter.Fill(table);

                        string Name = table.Rows[0]["Name"] as string;
                        string Username = table.Rows[0]["Username"] as string;
                        //string DivisionName = table.Rows[0]["DivisionName"] as string;
                        string JobTitle = table.Rows[0]["JobTitle"] as string;
                        string BadgeNo = table.Rows[0]["BadgeNo"].ToString();
                        //string role = table.Rows[0]["RoleName"] as string;

                        lblName.Text = Name;
                        lblUsername.Text = Username;
                        //lblDivision.Text = DivisionName;
                        lblJobTitle.Text = JobTitle;
                        lblBadgeNo.Text = BadgeNo;
                        //lblRole.Text = role;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    //If the user does not exist or a blank value has been entered
                    //Cancel the nextstep redirection and display an error message in a span
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    errorSpan.InnerText = "The user id specified is blank or does not exist";
                }

                break;
            case "WizardStep3":

                //Simply bind the radio list
                radio1.SelectedValue = lblRole.Text;
                break;
        }
    }
```

The query will show my the Name, Username, Division (or Department), Job Title and Badge Number in the Wizard Step2. Also, it should show me the role of the user in the wizard step 3 with enabling the Admin to insert and delete the role instead of updating the role.

I tested the query in the SQLServer Management Studio and it works well but when I put it in the C# code, I did not get any results in the web page and I don't know why.

Comment: Waaaay too much information. Could you try writing a wizard with just one step and tell us how it goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)The first problem I've spotted was the code from page load had to be moved to the Wizard1_NextButtonClick event.

2)I've removed the code for the Repeater and instead opted to place the info returned in step two into labels.

3)Implemented logic to update the users role in Step 3

4)Made minor changes to the HTML source, but otherwise it is mostly the same as you had it originally

The source and the code behind is displayed below, I've tested on my machine and it appears to be doing what you require, if you need any changes though please let me know:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" DisplaySideBar="false" Width="80%" ActiveStepIndex="2"
    OnNextButtonClick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Employee Username/Network ID">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="InputLabel">
                        Username:
                    </td>
                    <td class="InputControl">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <span id="errorSpan" runat="server" style="color:Red;"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Manage User">
            <div class="content">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblJobTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep3" runat="server" Title="Edit User Role">
            <label for="role">
                Current Role:
            </label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF99" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#000099" />
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radio1" runat="server" TextAlign="left">
                <asp:ListItem id="option1" runat="server" Value="Admin" />
                <asp:ListItem id="option2" runat="server" Value="Contribute" />
                <asp:ListItem id="option3" runat="server" Value="User" />
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Clicked" />
            <span id="infoSpan" runat="server" style="color:Red;"></span>
        </asp:WizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul id="wizHeader">
            <asp:Repeater ID="SideBarList" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:Wizard>


using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Set the Wizard Step 0 as the initial wizard step when the page loads
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //If one of the items is selected AND a username exists in the Username session object update the user role
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(radio1.SelectedValue) && Session["Username"] != null)
            {
                string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";
                string cmdText = "UPDATE employee SET Role = '" + radio1.SelectedValue + "'" + 
                    "WHERE Username = '" + Session["Username"].ToString() + "'";
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        infoSpan.InnerText = String.Format("The users role has been updated to - {0}", radio1.SelectedValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Method for checking the existence of the username in the database (retrun true or false)
        private bool CheckUsername(string username)
        {
            string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";
            string cmdText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM employee WHERE Username = '" + username + "'";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                // Open DB connection.
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
                {
                    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    // True (> 0) when the username exists, false (= 0) when the username does not exist.
                    return (count > 0);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (Wizard1.WizardSteps[e.NextStepIndex].ID)
            {
                case "WizardStep2":
                    string username = TextBox1.Text;
                    string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";

                    //For checking the user        
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && CheckUsername(username))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Session["Username"] = username; 

                            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                            conn.Open();
                            string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Username = @Username";
                            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
                            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                            DataTable table = new DataTable();
                            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
                            adapter.Fill(table);

                            string name = table.Rows[0]["Name"] as string;
                            string jobtitle = table.Rows[0]["JobTitle"] as string;
                            string role = table.Rows[0]["Role"] as string;

                            lblName.Text = name;
                            lblJobTitle.Text = jobtitle;
                            lblRole.Text = role;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        //If the user does not exist or a blank value has been entered
                        //Cancel the nextstep redirection and display an error message in a span
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        errorSpan.InnerText = "The user id specified is blank or does not exist";
                    }

                    break;
                case "WizardStep3":
                    //Simply bind the radio list
                    radio1.SelectedValue = lblRole.Text;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TIP:
Store your connection string in the web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then in code it can be accessed like so:

```
string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your code is very neat and amazing. You really did a great job and you save my life. I know that I should not ask you more after doing all of the work above, but I just need your help with something that I tried to add it to your code but I failed a lot of times. What I want is to show the user role which sets in another table and then gives the admin the ability to change this role. I know you did it above but you assumed that the role is in the same table of the user information. Please see the last edits in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Just Responding on your comment.

I think I've got a pretty good idea of how you want the code to be tweaked.Basically just had to do a few inner joins to retrieve the required info and store the role id in a session variable to make the update possible in wizard step 3.

Just a few things I'd like to note

1)The select query returns only the first result (TOP(1)), you can changes this accordingly and maybe bring back a repeater control if you think you may have more than one result returned from the db

2)It's not very flexible having inline queries in code i would suggest moving them into stored procs(there are alooooot of examples on the web on how to do this)

3)Instead of hardcoding the radio button list options rather retrieve them from the Roles table in the db,that way you can easily add\remove roles without having to re-deploy your site

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" DisplaySideBar="false" Width="80%" ActiveStepIndex="2"
    OnNextButtonClick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Employee Username/Network ID">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="InputLabel">
                        Username:
                    </td>
                    <td class="InputControl">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <span id="errorSpan" runat="server" style="color:Red;"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Manage User">
            <div class="content">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDepartment" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep3" runat="server" Title="Edit User Role">
            <label for="role">
                Current Role:
            </label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF99" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#000099" />
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radio1" runat="server" TextAlign="left">
                <asp:ListItem id="option1" runat="server" Value="1" Text="Admin" />
                <asp:ListItem id="option2" runat="server" Value="2" Text="Contribute" />
                <asp:ListItem id="option3" runat="server" Value="3" Text="User" />
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Clicked" />
            <span id="infoSpan" runat="server" style="color:Red;"></span>
        </asp:WizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul id="wizHeader">
            <asp:Repeater ID="SideBarList" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:Wizard>

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Set the Wizard Step 1 as the initial wizard step when the page loads
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //If one of the items is selected AND a username exists in the Username session object update the user role
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(radio1.SelectedValue) && Session["Username"] != null)
            {
                string cmdText = "UPDATE Userrole SET RoleId = '" + radio1.SelectedValue + "'" +
                    "WHERE Username = '" + Session["Username"].ToString() + "'";
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        infoSpan.InnerText = String.Format("The users role has been updated to - {0}", radio1.SelectedItem.Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Method for checking the existence of the username in the database (retrun true or false)
        private bool CheckUsername(string username)
        {
            string cmdText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM users WHERE Username = '" + username + "'";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                // Open DB connection.
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
                {
                    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    // True (> 0) when the username exists, false (= 0) when the username does not exist.
                    return (count > 0);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (Wizard1.WizardSteps[e.NextStepIndex].ID)
            {
                case "WizardStep2":
                    string username = TextBox1.Text;

                    //For checking the user        
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && CheckUsername(username))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Session["Username"] = username;

                            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                            conn.Open();
                            //string cmdText = "SELECT FROM employee WHERE Username = @Username";
                            string cmdText = "SELECT TOP(1) [Name],Department,RoleName,r.RoleId AS [RoleId] FROM users " +
                            "INNER JOIN userrole u on u.username = users.username " +
                            "INNER JOIN roles r on r.roleid = u.roleid " +
                            "WHERE users.username = @Username ";

                            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
                            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                            DataTable table = new DataTable();
                            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
                            adapter.Fill(table);

                            string name = table.Rows[0]["Name"] as string;
                            string department = table.Rows[0]["Department"] as string;
                            string role = table.Rows[0]["RoleName"] as string;
                            Session["RoleId"] = table.Rows[0]["RoleId"];

                            lblName.Text = name;
                            lblDepartment.Text = department;
                            lblRole.Text = role;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        //If the user does not exist or a blank value has been entered
                        //Cancel the nextstep redirection and display an error message in a span
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        errorSpan.InnerText = "The user id specified is blank or does not exist";
                    }

                    break;
                case "WizardStep3":
                    //Simply bind the radio list if the list contains the role retrieved
                    var roleId = Session["RoleId"];
                    if (roleId != null && radio1.Items.FindByValue(roleId.ToString()) != null)
                    {
                        radio1.SelectedValue = Session["RoleId"].ToString();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Again you did a very nice job. You let my life easy especially with the Roles issue. However, I still have a problem with the SQL query in the C# code. I did not use yours, because my database design is different than what you used. I don't know if you can help me with this issue. I updated my question above just to give you an idea about the problem that I have.